# Valid Regex statement is not a valid match in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a very simple regex statement to tell me if a String contains a match.

The Regex statement:

```
%.+%
```

The String I'm scanning:

```
"Property:%substitute.candidate%_substitute.candidate%End"
```

I've used an the online the tools to validate my work and using the supplied Regex and the given String that it is a match. however when I run it in my Java program it does not return as a match.

In my Java Code I'm using the following to match the string.

```
if(replacedString.matches(regex)){}
```

Can anyone explain the reason why it is not working?

Comment: you should adjust your regexp too, because it uses a hungry approach, therefore try `%[^%]+%` instead of `%.+%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matches()` expects the ENTIRE string to be matched.

What you want, is a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("%.+%");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Property:%substitute.candidate%_substitute.candidate%End");
if (m.find()) { // found it }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

The *problem* is that when you use `matches()`, the engine will add the `^` and `$` anchors so that your string must *match exactly*.

In your case, the `matches` is expecting that the string starts and ends with `%`, which is not the case.

To go around this, use `find()`.

EDIT: As per @Pshemo's comment, you would need to do this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%.+%");
String str = "...";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `String` doesn't have `find` method which may be confusing for OP.

Comment: @Pshemo: I see what you mean, I though he was already using the `Pattern` class. Amended my answer as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

String#matches() takes a regex as parameter and ^ and $ are the implicit anchors. So, the matches method matches the entire string. You can choose to either try matching the whole string like this : mystring.matches(".*your_regex.*"); or try using a pattern/matcher in combination with find/replace as mentioned in previous answer

Comment: Correct. Now instead of posting it as comment (which not everyone reads) [edit] your post and place this explanation there.